# 404 page when switching stores on magento product pages

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

i am trying to fix the following problem:

When i create a new product, i always give the english store a different url than the german store. On the frontend when i switch from the german store to the english store, it returns a 404 page. on the german product page the country id (de) is in the url (http://website/de/product1.html). But when i switch to the 
english store the link looks like this: http://website/product1.html (without country id). And that gives me a 404 page!

Note: When i add the "en" country id to the url it works perfect.

can someone help me resolve this issue?

Magento Version 1.7.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to change your english storeview base URL :

1. go to System -> Config then choose your english store view
2. then, in the config panel, go to general -> web
3. in "secure" -> Base URL uncheck "use website" and add en/ at the end of the URL.
4. do the same in in "unsecure"

I expect it will work.

Comment: Thanks. I already have the store id (/en) on pages and on products that have the same URLs on both stores. This occurs only if i choose different urls for the products on both stores!

Comment: So, I tried. I have one product with different URLs in my french and english store. I works perfecly, and I don't have any store id in the URL. :/

Comment: Thanks for trying thhis out!! you can try it also on my website: http://bengar.de/de/echolothalterung-fuer-schlauchboot.html. try to switch the store from the language icons.

Comment: ok I've seen it on your website. So, why do you have "/de" or /en ? did you add this in the config as base URLs ? you can also go to "catalog --> URL rewrite management" and look at what you have there

Comment: I've set those codes under "configuration" --> "manage stores".

Comment: I already removed any suspiscious urls from the rewrite management. I have this problem with every product, not with just one specific product.

Comment: When I created this product with different URLs, I had three new lines in my URL rewrite management. Maybe you have a line for each product

Comment: When i set "use website" on the english store of the product. It works perfectly even with the store code. Your can see this on the same page now. The problem occurs as i said only if i choose 2 different urls. I don't use rewrites to avoid those problems!

Comment: I know and I understand that, but Magento might do this rewrites himself without you agree when you choose two different URL's. I don't know, I don't have the issue and I can't reproduce it to see differences in the backend.

Comment: Thank you very much for trying to help me. I hope someone can help. you can filter system rewrites (Magento) from user rewirtes. And nothing special..

Comment: How many products do you have ? If you have not so much, you could create redirection for each of them, from yourstore/your-english-product to yourstore/en/your-english-product, and the same for german products.